# Apache breaks on PHP's 'echo' function

Tags: php, apache, magento2

I am installing new environment on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2.
I have installed Php7.1, Mysql, PMA and using default apache.
I am installing Magento 2 on a separate virtual host. I have enabled mod_rewrite for apache.
But when i try to enter frontend page i get
`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`
error in browser. But that only for frontend page. Admin area works properly. I am able to log in and navigate all pages.
I added

```
echo 1; die;
```

at the beginning of index.php file and found out that it was not even used.
Experimentally I found that if I comment

`RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

in magento's default .htaccess file, index.php is being used, but i still get same error.
I debugged and found, that everything breaks in this piece of code:

```
echo $this->getContent();
```

getContent return code of a whole page. And php is not executed after this part. If i change it to something like
echo 123;
result is the same. What is really strange for me that echo function works in index.php but doesn't work here.
I really feel like it's apache error but can't really find what's the problem.

Here is an error that is given in apache logs:

```
[Sat Jan 18 21:55:16.091252 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4308] AH00052: child pid 6280 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

But i can't find anything that would really help me to solve this. I am really curios why it's working for some links and does not for others.
I would've been really thankful for any advices.

P.S. everything works good on another PC with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: PHP 7.1 is end-of-life. First thing I'd do is try a more recent version.

Comment: Maybe step debug with xdebug to see where it fails or run dtrace / strace / valgrind depending on what's available in your environment

Comment: @AlexHowansky I might be using magento which does not support a version higher that 7.1. So I need it to be working on this one.

Comment: @JonasOsburg if you mean debugging php code, than i have already done that and described it in a post.

Comment: No, I mean attach a debugger (xdebug) and step trough the code till mod_php crashes. Or alternatively use an external program like dtrace on mac os and attach it to apache and its sub processes and check what happens before it dies.

Comment: No php code of yours should be able to crash php with segmentation fault. Something is wrong with your installation.

Comment: @C.B. That's what i'm thinking. But admin area works fine, so something is wrong with settings i believe

Comment: It's definitely possible to write php code that segfaults, check for example https://github.com/hannob/php-crashers?files=1 as I said, attach a step debugger or something that reports what the process is doing before it crashes. Without further information it will be very hard to help you out here.

Comment: i disabled default mac's apache and installed another one with brew and everything work good now. Thanks everyone for advices :)